# electron: how to set text on about for Darwin/OS X

Tags: electron

I just finished my first electron package but I can't find any tutorial or example on how to set the "about" pop up on Mac OS X - Darwin.

What I have so far is

```
const menuTemplate = [
    ...(process.platform == 'darwin'? [{
        label: app.getName(),
        submenu: [
       {role: 'about'}
       ]
       }] : []),
    {
        label: "File",
        submenu: [
            {
                label: "Save",
                accelerator: "CmdOrCtrl+S",
                click(){ win.webContents.send('save-clicked')}
            },

            {
                label: "Save As",
                accelerator: "CmdOrCtrl+Shift+S",
                click(){ 
                    filePath = undefined
                    win.webContents.send('save-clicked')
                }
            }
        ]
    },

    {role: "editMenu"},
    {role: "viewMenu"}
```

I assume that something has to be set after role:'about' but not sure what :)

Comment: is there any error ?

Comment: @raman no error but on the about it just shows the app name and version taken from the package.json file

Comment: that the standard process btw, the name and version will always be based on package.json file

Comment: @raman I know that but the question is how to add more elements e.g. author, copyright, website on the about window

Comment: ohm thanks, i got it.

Answer (score 0):

there is actually a way to that, we need to create an another browser window rather than using the default process. Hope this will work.

```
const menuTemplate = [
    ...(process.platform == 'darwin'? [{
        label: app.getName(),
        submenu: [{
         label: 'about',
         click: () => //Do something here to create a new browser window with necessary requirement,
        }]
       }] : []),
    {
        label: "File",
        submenu: [
            {
                label: "Save",
                accelerator: "CmdOrCtrl+S",
                click(){ win.webContents.send('save-clicked')}
            },

            {
                label: "Save As",
                accelerator: "CmdOrCtrl+Shift+S",
                click(){ 
                    filePath = undefined
                    win.webContents.send('save-clicked')
                }
            }
        ]
    },
```